Why does my thermostat gangbox have 6 wires?
Why might my gangbox have 6 wires? (plus 3 ground wires not in the picture)

Two wires are connected to a mechanical thermostat controlling a 240v heater. The wires are labeled: load & line.
The black 'load' labeled wire goes directly out of the box presumably to the heater.
The red 'line' labeled wire is connected to a wire nut with two other black wires.
There are two wire nuts, each connecting three wires:

Nut 1 (first 120v line + thermostat):

black wire labeled 'line' from thermostat
black L1 from the panel,
black wire (back from the heater?)


Nut 2 (second 120v line)

red L2 from panel,
red wire to heater,
red wire from heater





I would have assumed that there'd be only the two 120v wires going to the heater, but there are 2 additional wires. What might those wires be doing?


Can we assume the two rectangles at the bottom of your square box are just the openings where wires pass through?  Are you certain there is not another heater supplied by this circuit?  It could just be wires carrying power to another heater - likely with its own thermostat.

Are you sure all 4 wires go to the same heater?  If so can you provide its model number or even  photo of its spec plate, and can you open the cover and see how they are connected?  Perhaps it has an emergency frost-prevention mode requiring unswitched power?  That's a WAG.

Yes, the rectangles at the bottom are the ports of the gang box. There's a thermostat on the other side of this wall, so they could be connected.

You say there is another thermostat but you drew the second set of wires going to the heater.  Do you know that or is it a guess?  Can you open up the heater and see what's going on inside?
